# PDO mysql creating table unsuccessful

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have successfully create the database if not exists in PDO. But when I tried to create table it says unknown database. Its says unknown database. Thank you for your help guys. probably got some error

Here is my code

```
<?php

    $host='localhost'; // Host name 
    $username='root'; // Mysql username 
    $password=''; // Mysql password 
    $database_name = "db_airlines"; // Database name 
    $tbl_name="users"; // Table name


try{
        $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost", $username, $password);
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        $database_name = "`".str_replace("`","``",$database_name)."`";
        $pdo->query("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS $database_name");
        $pdo->query("use $database_name");

        $pdo = null;

    }catch(Exception $e){
        echo "database creation failed";
    }

    try{
         $db = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $host . ';dbname=' . $database_name, $username, $password);
         $db->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );//Error Handling
         $sql ="CREATE table $tbl_name(
         user_ID INT( 11 ) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
         Lastname VARCHAR( 250 ) NOT NULL, 
         Middle Name VARCHAR( 250 ) NOT NULL,
         Fistname VARCHAR( 250 ) NOT NULL, 
         Email VARCHAR( 250 ) NOT NULL, 
         Account_name VARCHAR( 250 ) NOT NULL, 
         password VARCHAR( 250 ) NOT NULL);" ;
         $db->exec($sql);
     }catch(Exception $e){
        die('error : ' . $e->getMessage());
     }

?>
```

Comment: where is create table code?

Comment: sorry it's already there i have edited the post

Comment: what is the exact error??

Comment: just try `CREATE TABLE {$database_name}.{$tbl_name}(` see if that works if it does it would mean when you connect it's failing to login to the database not sure why but would be first test

Comment: oh and just a passing note you should not be killing a PDO connection then re-opening it resources are finite

Comment: same problem. error : SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database '`db_airlines`'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $host . ';dbname=' . $database_name, $username, $password);
```

Here `$database_name` isn't `db_airlines`, but

```
`db_airlines`
```

from the previous

```
$database_name = "`".str_replace("`","``",$database_name)."`";
```

So, try to change it in:

```
$database_name_quoted = "`".str_replace("`","``",$database_name)."`";
$pdo->query("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS $database_name_quoted");
$pdo->query("use $database_name_quoted");
```

Comment: Still I do not understand why it took so long to us to notice it.

Answer (score 1):

Your sql is not correct

```
Middle Name VARCHAR( 250 ) NOT NULL,
      |
```

Space is not allowed in column name

make it `Middle_Name`

**UPDATE**

space is allowed in column name just write it in between (`)

Comment: or wrap the column name with backticks (`)

Comment: good spot but should not give the error he's getting should give a syntax error. could be OP getting wrong error info though

Comment: still error : SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database '`db_airlines`'

Comment: `user_ID` INT( 11 ) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
      `Lastname` VARCHAR( 250 ) NOT NULL, 
      `Middle_Name` VARCHAR( 250 ) NOT NULL,
      `Fistname` VARCHAR( 250 ) NOT NULL, 
      `Email` VARCHAR( 250 ) NOT NULL, 
      `Account_name` VARCHAR( 250 ) NOT NULL, still database unknown I have already put (`) in between

Comment: check in `workbench` or `phpmyadmin` if database is really created?